# Serve different resources based on request type?

Tags: html, browser

Not sure if this is a thing.

I'd like to be able to hand out a link to a gif: http://www.example.com/this.gif

If it's pasted into, say, Facebook chat, I'd like it to appear as if I linked a normal gif, so the preview loads like it normally would. However, if a user directly accesses the gif by pasting it into their address bar, I'd like to redirect them to another page.

Any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Try something with `.htaccess` but I don't think that you can check origin of request.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not differentiation by request type (the HTTP request is GET in both cases), but by *referrer*. For this, you can inspect the `Referer` (sic) header. When a page contains e.g. an `img` element, a GET request is generated, with the the URL specified in the `Referer` header, unless the browser has been configured not to send it (possible, but rare). When the URL of an image is entered directly in the browser’s address bar, a GET request with no `Referer` header is generated.

You can thus decide e.g. to do some redirect if no `Referer` header is present. The way to implement this depends on the software used server-side.

Comment: I've tested this both ways, and I don't see a Referer header anywhere in the request objects?

Comment: How did you test it? If you look at any page containing image and use a browser’s Developer Tools, Network tab, you should see request headers containing `Referer` lines.